# How to extract embedded resource from a namespace with special characters?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to extract an embedded resource to VB.Net project (build action : Embedded resource) using the following command :

```
Dim StreamReader As StreamReader

StreamReader = New StreamReader(Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(NameSpaceName & "." & FileName))
```

Where Assembly is the executing assembly.

The file name is **"file.sql"** the namespacename is like **"A.B.C"** but the result of GetManifestResourceStream is nothing

Does anyone know how to use the a namespace name with some special charachters on it please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to returns the names of all the resources in the assembly.